# How does webpage navigations work in pwa for windows store app(appx)?

Tags: windows-10, windows-store, progressive-web-app

I have a query regarding **PWA** for which I would appreciate some feedback. Say, I have a page similar to this [makemytrip coupons](https://www.grabon.in/makemytrip-coupons/) page which lists coupons and deals. On clicking any coupon, it will redirect the user to some other page. I want to convert this to PWA and push an **APPX** to the windows store.

But I haven't observed a windows store application opening a new instance. 
Is there an option of doing this? If so, what are the **pros** and **cons** when compared to web?

Will there be any difference in the way how **cookies** are operated when compared to web application?

Is **GTM** (or any such analytics tools) the only way to track the device from which the request is coming through (as in is there any specific application or tool to track the behavior of PWA)?